# Step pyramid scale equally?

Tags: modeling, transforms

I am having a problem that I am sure is something that I just don't understand. Very much still learning.

I have this step pyramid (from the "extra mesh addon") and I want to scale the edges in straight to keep the lip but to add an angle faces. See photos

As you can see when I scale it is not equal at all.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scaling requires an origin point to compute the steps. The closer the vertex is to the origin the smaller the step will be, that's the whole point of scaling.
Thus becoming uneven in this case.

Here we don't really need scaling, what we want to do is "move" the vertices evenly toward the center.

One solution would be to:

- Select all the edges as you did before
- press "G then G again", it will trigger the "move along edge" feature.
- Then move all your selected edge along the corner edge which point to the center of the pyramid

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I know I was missing something and I won't be forgetting it for a long time too.

Answer (score 1):

...just because it's fun: Here is the solution for *Geometry Nodes*:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>